# getpivotdata from external source with #REF error

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi I had a pivot table where I extract dtaa with the following foromula:
IF(ISERR(GETPIVOTDATA("Received Quantity";'FA pivot'!$A$7;"Hard failure";"NO";"MFG2 Month";1;"MFG2 Year";2014));0;GETPIVOTDATA("Received Quantity";'FA pivot'!$A$7;"Hard failure";"NO";"MFG2 Month";1;"MFG2 Year";2014))

From some days I linked the origin table to an access table but if I now run the pivot (fa pivot) the results of the fromula above is 0 due a #ref error in getpivotdata. How I can link getpivotdata to external data)

Answer (score 0):

`GETPIVOTDATA` returns `#REF` if the pivot value is not available in the pivot table. This can happen if you change filters, rows, or columns in the pivot table or the values are no longer available, e.g. due to a refresh of the data.

Comment: Yes it's true. I solved my issue removing the row labels and insert again. Now it's work. thanks